# Echo to clipboard with special characters

Tags: cmd.exe, escape-characters

I believe I am using the commands correctly, but the clipboard is empty using the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c echo 28376^>1847|clip
```

I believe the problem is the `>` which I am using, and I use the `^` escape character to override.

Any suggestion as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What is wrong?

> the clipboard is empty using the following:
>
> ```
> echo 28376^>1847|clip
> ```

The reason it doesn't work as expected is:

> When piping or redirecting text, applying an escape character gets a little more complex, a pipe will start two new cmd.exe instances, each of these cmd processes are passed one side of the pipe and will parse their part once again (with the cmd-line parser, not with the batch-line-parser).

Source: [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

So you need **extra** escape characters:

```
echo 28376^^^>1847|clip
```

Now, the first caret escapes the second caret `^`, the third caret escapes the `>` so now the new `cmd` instance inherits `>&`

Further Reading: [batch file - Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192318/why-does-delayed-expansion-fail-when-inside-a-piped-block-of-code)

Comment: Interesting didn't know cmd would act like this when piping...